# Android Lollipop, app icon not change

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-icons

App is already on market.
I want App icon change , and i make New Apk (include new icon).

(1) market download my app (old app icon)
(2) install new apk (new app icon)

but, Android Lollipop OS device is not change (Other os device is change new app icon)

why can't change?
this case, how to change app icon ?
help plz.

Comment: How long have you waited after publishing the new apk and reinstalling it?

Comment: lollipop device reboot after, icon change ~!